# How to apply .axes more efficiently - example axes.spines single code for 'right' and 'top'?

Tags: python

This will help me with a broad range of solutions.

Is it possible to cover multiple axes in the same code instead of having to write axes.spine twice...I do not want to have to do it twice, each for 'right' and once for 'top'...but instead just say 'right' and 'top' for example

```
axes.spines['right'].set_visible(False); axes.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def lol():
    axes.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    axes.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
```

Then use it with

```
lol()
```

You can define your function, which you defined with def, in almost any context, even in another function. However, you must make sure that the variables used are present at the moment you call the function. Google for `python function arguments` if you like.